# Android open gallery is not working in my code

Tags: java, android, image-gallery

I'm trying this code to open the gallery. My app makes a directory in the gallery. I can see my directory in the gallery. I'm trying to open it from my app by this code:-

```
        File sdDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File f = new File(sdDir, "Photo Location Note");
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setDataAndType(Uri.withAppendedPath(Uri.fromFile(f), "Photo Location Note"), "image/*");
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(i);
```

It opens the gallery and shows a toast message as "Unable to find item". It doesn't open my directory "Photo Location Note" in the gallery.

How can I open my directory "Photo Location Note" in the gallery?

Comment: Have you set the Storage permissions on AndroidManifest?

Comment: Well, if nothing else, you have `Photo Location Note` twice in your `Uri` (once in the `File` and once via `withAppendedPath()`), and no file extension, neither of which seem correct. Make sure that the `Uri` that you put in the `Intent` makes sense.

Comment: @CommonsWare Could you please explain with source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me on Android 11 and earlier versions:

```
    public void openPhoto(Context context, String directory){

    File file = new File(directory);
    if(!file.exists()){
        return;
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N ?
                    FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,context.getPackageName() + ".provider", file) : Uri.fromFile(file),"image/*");

    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    intent = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open File");
    context.startActivity(intent);


}
```

This fragment is important:
`intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);`